# How to rewind multiple videos at the same time. Java HTML5

Tags: html, video, skip, simultaneous

I am new to this, tried to search for information but I could not find anything that would fit my needs.
I am trying to make 2 videos be controlled at exactly the same time. I managed to play and pause at the same time. But when I try to make a rewind/fast forward button, the same syntax does not work..
To make things clear, I am giving the code examples.
This one makes all 4 videos play & pause at the same time:
`function vidplay() {
       var video1 = document.getElementById("Video1");
       var video2 = document.getElementById("Video2");
       var button = document.getElementById("play");
       if (video1.paused) {
          video1.play() & video2.play();
          button.textContent = "||";
       } else {
          video1.pause() & video2.pause();
          button.textContent = ">";
       }
    }`

But this one does not complete my goal:

`function vidskip() {
        var video1 = document.getElementById("Video1");
        var video2 = document.getElementById("Video2");
        video1.currentTime = 15;
        video2.currentTime = 15;
     }`

The thing is, script executes `video1.currentTime = 15;` and then executes `video2.currentTime = 15;` and on one click it rewinds . I need them to be executed at exactly the same time. Anyone has an idea how to do this?

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: @BrianRoach maybe the fact that it uses javascript?

Comment: Which **has nothing to do with Java**, being my point. I removed the tag.

Comment: Sorry then. Any idea about topic?